# Saxon PDF tutorials?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, pdf, saxon

Does anyone know a good set of Saxon XML, XSLT, PDF ([link text](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/dotnet/dotnetapi.html)) tutorials for .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the saxon-resources zip which includes C# samples.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/